# Does #pragma exclude_renderers increase performance?

Tags: unity-game-engine, glsl, shader, hlsl

I think i heard somewhere in article but forgot it already. It say if i excluded renderers performance will be better for shader because it will skip the checking. is it true ?

Ex :

> #pragma exclude_renderers d3d11_9x xbox360 xboxone ps3 ps4 psp2

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of `exclude_renderers` is to improve shader compilation time, but it also enables you to use some language features that are not available on some platforms. From the [manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-ShaderPrograms.html):

> You can indicate which renderers to compile to using #pragma
>   only_renderers or #pragma exclude_renderers directives. This is mostly
>   useful in cases where you are explicitly using some shader language
>   features that you know aren’t possible on some platforms.

Comment: increase shader compilation time ? so does it affect the performance ?

Comment: whoops, I meant "improve" or decrease.

Comment: ok now it make sense, but when is the shader compilation take place ? is it on editor ? build time ? or when running the apps ?.

Comment: OpenGL shaders must be compiled at least once when running the apps, but D3D shaders can be compiled on build-time.